# Bulk file rename - remove certain part of a file name

Tags: windows, rename, batch-rename, bulk

I have lots of files where I want to replace the first part of the file name (before the last "_") with an "e".

```
tom_&_jerry-s03e12_3089.jpg
mickey_mouse-s06e02_16091.jpg
peppa_pig-s06e04_23092.jpg
phineas_and_ferb-s03e23_23098.jpg
the_fairly_oddparents-s02e18_7100.jpg
foster's_home_for_imaginary_friends-s05e07_23102.jpg
futurama-s03e01_104.jpg


e_3089.jpg
e_16091.jpg
e_23092.jpg
e_23098.jpg
e_7100.jpg
e_23102.jpg
e_104.jpg
```

How can I script this?

Comment: Start with `for /?` and read http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html or simply find solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=windows+file+rename